# Difference between duplicate_term/2 and copy_term/2 in SWI-Prolog

Tags: swi-prolog

What is the difference between [duplicate_term/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=duplicate_term/2) and [copy_term/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=copy_term/2) in SWI-Prolog?

Can you give an input on which they show different behaviors?

Comment: It shows if you use setarg/3. But then, you really should not use setarg/3 - completely malaprop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider for example:

```
?- X = f(a),
   copy_term(X, Y),
   setarg(1, X, b).
X = Y, Y = f(b).
```

In contrast, creating a **true copy** with `duplicate_term/2`:

```
?- X = f(a),
   duplicate_term(X, Y),
   setarg(1, X, b).
X = f(b),
Y = f(a).
```

If this difference is problematic in your application, chances are that your code can be improved by using **pure** constructs that are less error-prone.

For example, consider using **attributed variables** as a somewhat more declarative alternative for destructive modifications, if you cannot live without them. The least error-prone and most general approach is typically to stick to pure methods throughout. If necessary, come up with clean declarative interfaces, and hide impurities behind them.

Comment: Would be nice some example to be on the SWI-Prolog documentation page too.

Comment: It may definitely seem nice and desirable at first. However, this may also draw more attention to such low-level constructs and thus even contribute to their use although the documentation itself already strongly advises against it. Personally, I would prefer to instead give more room to pure constructs that are free from such pitfalls, ideally eschewing the error-prone low-level predicates entirely. As one example of "overexplaining missing the point", consider the lengthy discussions of `!/0` in Prolog textbooks: Many pages of text, a complicated classification, yet still so many red `!/0`!

Comment: There is no guarantee whatsoever that given examples work as you indicate. You are just observing that behavior currently.

Comment: The second case is *explicitly guaranteed* in the documentation. The first case is not.

Comment: If you wrap `setof(t, G_0, [t])` around the last two goals the result changes for both `copy_term/2` and `duplicate_term/2`.

Comment: ... currently, I should add.